# How do I add chart points together?

Tags: arithmetic, graphing-functions

In this video, [two points on a chart are added together](https://youtu.be/3S9eZRHjP8g?t=238). As each individual point has X and Y values, how is addition performed?

I've researched 'adding chart points' and variations thereof but not found anything.

Comment: This is how points on elliptic curves are added. You can google "addition on elliptic curves" to get many explanations. This may also help: http://www.math.vt.edu/people/brown/class_homepages/elliptic_curve_addition.pdf

Comment: You are very welcome. Maybe you got downvoted because you didn't add any detail to your question. One may argue that you could have googled this on your own, but how can you google something when you don't know what it actually is. So don't worry!

Comment: Hehe exactly! I actually did google 'adding chart points' etc. thinking it was some generic charting thing before you told me this was EC-specific. Thanks @sranthrop!

Comment: May I ask why you are interested in this topic?

Comment: Elliptic curves are abelian groups in addition to their underlying algebraic structure. It's possible to write out the group law explicitly, but it derives more naturally from applying Riemann-Roch.

Comment: @sranthrop I'd like to understand more about how ECC works, as I already understand RSA and ECC has much better strength to CPU speed.

Comment: Ah nice. Then maybe this will help: http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how points on elliptic curves are added. You can google "addition on elliptic curves" to get many explanations. This may also help: http://www.math.vt.edu/people/brown/class_homepages/elliptic_curve_addition.pdf

Answer (score 1):

My students used to have trouble with this idea too, and it came down to this:  you don't add the x-values of the point, you just add the y-values.

That's really all you need to know, but if you want to think more deeply, this goes back to how functions are designed.  All that the x-value tells us is where we are looking on the graph.  The x-axis itself is more of a locater than anything else.  The y-values are what we are interested in, as long as we keep in mind which x-value they are located at.

Once you understand this idea the more detailed explanations will make more sense.